# Different realms with multiple WebSecurityConfigurerAdapters

Tags: spring-security

I have a Spring Security configuration where I want requests to `/stats` to be secured in a different realm than all other requests, i.e. when I navigate to `/` I will be prompted with a HTTP basic login form and after I login and navigate to `/stats` there is another HTTP basic login form since I'm not yet logged in in that realm. The problem with my current configuration is that once I'm logged in at `/` and navigate to `/stats` I get a 403 as I'm already logged in but with a different authority. Here is my configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
public class PortalServiceSecurityConfig {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    static class StatsWebSecConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                        .withUser("user").password("password").authorities("STATS");
        }

        @Bean
        public AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint() {
            final BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint = new BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint();
            entryPoint.setRealmName("stats realm");
            return entryPoint;
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/stats").authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/stats").hasAuthority("STATS")
                .and().httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint());
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    static class PortalServiceConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private WebserviceAuthenticationConfiguration configService;

        @Autowired
        private SoapFaultDetailtConverter soapFaulDetailtConverter;

        @Bean
        @Override
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }

        @Bean
        @Override
        protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
            return new DefaultPortalSecurityService(configService);
        }


        @Bean
        SecurityWebApplicationInitializer securityWebApplicationInitializer() {
            return new SecurityWebApplicationInitializer();
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        }

        @Bean
        public AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint() {
            final BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint = new BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint();
            entryPoint.setRealmName("ws realm");
            return entryPoint;
        }


        @Override
        protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().hasAuthority("WEBSERVICE")
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @dur you are right. I updated the description but now the /stats configuration seems to be ignored entirely

Comment: There was a unrelated problem with the deployment of the war. Now with the configuration above the problem still persists. I tried adding `web.ignoring().antMatchers("/stats");` to the PortalServiceConfig but when I navigate to `/stats` without being authenticated `/stats` is served without login form as if StatsWebSecConfig is completely ignored.

Comment: Try following: `.httpBasic().realmName("ws realm")` instead of `.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint());` and remove your `authenticationEntryPoint()` methods.

Comment: Doesn't work either. We go with the solution of two separate wars.